# Passing alias as argument in bash

Tags: bash, calendar, alias

You can use built in command cal for example in this way:

```
cal 10 2013
```

and you will get a calendar of Octber 2013. My teacher made and assignment to change first argument in a way, that we could call this function in our native language. For example:

```
cal spalis 2013
cal gruodis 1999
```

and so on..
(spalis means october, and gruodis -december in my country)
And we would see same result as cal 10 2013 or cal gruodis 1999

Same goes with others months. I am newbie in shell, and thought that i could make an alias:

```
alias spalis=10
```

and then i tried to use cal spalis 2013, but i got error:

```
cal: spalis is neither a month number (1..12) nor a name
```

So, after googling for a while, i guess there is no way to pass alias as an argument? Or i'am doing something wrong? Maybe there is some other way? I'll be very thankful for an advice and sorry for bad english :)

Answer (score 2):

Aliases only work for the command name, not for arguments. What you'll want to do is write a function `cal` which replaces the first argument with the appropriate number and then calls the regular `cal` binary.

```
cal() {
    local month=$1
    local year=$2

    # replace named $month with a numeric $month here
    ...

    # Call the real cal. `command' ignores this function and calls the underlying binary.
    command cal "$month" "$year"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`cal` accepts month names in the language specified by the current locale. To accept Lithuanian month names, use

```
$ LANG=lt_LT cal spalis 2013
Spalio 2013
Sk Pr An Tr Kt Pn Št
       1  2  3  4  5
 6  7  8  9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24 25 26
27 28 29 30 31
```

This depends on the version of `cal` you are using. The above works on my MacOS X 10.9 machine, but not on one of my Linux boxes (where `cal` doesn't accept month names at all, only numbers).

This may not be exactly what your teacher is looking for, as it only requires using the program as intended. :)